# iOS: Wait for asynchronous method before populating a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I'm getting some data from my server that I need to use as metadata for creating a table view. The problem is the data loads asynchronously with the flow of the app. I'm sure this is probably a simple fix, but how can I either pause the flow of the app until the data has loaded from the server, or update the table view as the data becomes available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that your data source methods are written correctly so that if there is no data yet, the table will indeed be empty. This is because the data source methods will be called when the table first appears, which is before you have data.

Then, when there *is* data, just call `reloadData` (on the main thread!). The same data source methods will run *again*, but this time there is data.

Comment: Glad to help. And as another answer has already pointed out, you can cover the delay psychologically (for the user) with an activity view or similar. You might even want to turn off user interaction temporarily to force the user to wait patiently, but don't do that for too long or you'll be killed by the watchdog process.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an UIActivityIndicatorView to show the data is being downloaded. Once the data is downloaded in async mode you can reload UITableView.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
```

Now call your method that downloads data from the network.

```
[self asyncDownloadMethod];
```

When you are notified i.e., by any delegate that the contents are downloaded, stop the indicator.

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to answer definitively, but the gist of it is you need to set up a `delegate` that will handle populating the table view once you've finished loading your data.

For example, the NSURLConnection class defines the [`connectionWithRequest:delegate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/connectionWithRequest%3adelegate%3a) selector for loading data asynchronously.  The `delegate` argument is defined as:

> **delegate**
>   The delegate object for the connection. The connection calls methods on this delegate as the load progresses. Delegate methods are called on the same thread that called this method. For the connection to work correctly, the calling thread’s run loop must be operating in the default run loop mode.